# ksh su -c return value

Tags: linux, ksh, su

inside of my script I need to run two scripts as another user, so I used the following line:

```
su otherUser -c "firstScript;secondScript;status=$?"
echo "returning $status"
return $status
```

The problem is that $status will always return 0.I did test with secondScript failing (wrong argument). Not sure if it's because I exited otherUser or if the $status is actually the result of the su command. Any suggestions?!

Comment: Because the assignment to `status` is inside the quotes, it's assigned to the inner shell running as `otherUser`, *not* in the outer shell at all. Thus, this code -- run in isolation -- would emit `returning ` as output with no numeric exit value at all (and then, lacking an explicit argument to `return`, would return the exit status of the `echo` command, which would be 0 barring an unusual error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture `status` inside your outer shell, not in the inner shell invoked by `su`; otherwise, the captured value is thrown away as soon as that inner shell exits.

This is made much easier because `su` passes through the exit status of the command it runs -- if that command exits with a nonzero status, so will `su`.

```
su otherUser -c 'firstScript; secondScript'; status=$?
echo "returning $status"
return $status
```

Note that this only returns the exit status of `secondScript` (as would your original code have done, were it working correctly). You might think about what you want to do if `firstScript` fails.

---

Now, it's a little more interesting if you only want to return the exit code of `firstScript`; in that case, you need to capture the exit status in *both* shells:

```
su otherUser -c 'firstScript; status=$?; secondScript; exit $status'); status=$?
echo "returning $status"
return $status
```

---

If you want to run `secondScript` only if `firstScript` succeeds, and return a nonzero value if either of them fails, it becomes easy again:

```
su otherUser -c 'firstScript && secondScript'); status=$?
echo "returning $status"
return $status
```